# List coming back as null after unmarshalling into a POJO using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

I am trying to unmarshall an XML into Java POJO using JAXB, all elements are getting unmarshalled fine except for the lists(listId1 and listId2), following is the xml, the pojo classes and the business class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abacus-1.0-snapshot xmlns="urn:xxxxxxx">
    <rules>
        <rule>
            <name>rule1</name>
            <errorType>WARNING</errorType>
            <flag>true</flag>
            <startDate>2020-05-19</startDate>
            <listId1>
                <id>100101</id>
                <id>100102</id>
            </listId1>
            <listId2>
                <id>100103</id>
                <id>100104</id>
            </listId2>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <name>rule2</name>
            <errorType>ERROR</errorType>
            <flag>false</flag>
            <startDate>2020-05-20</startDate>
            <listId1>
                <id>100105</id>
                <id>100106</id>
            </listId1>
            <listId2>
                <id>100107</id>
                <id>100107</id>
            </listId2>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</abacus-1.0-snapshot>
```

The Rules.java which maps the <rules> element to Rules.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "rules", namespace = "urn:xxxxxxx")
public class RulesPOJO
{

    @XmlElement(name = "rule", namespace = "urn:xxxxxxx")
    private final List<rulePOJO> rulesPOJO = new ArrayList<rulePOJO>();

    public List<rulePOJO> getRulesPOJO()
    {
        return rulesPOJO;
    }
}
```

The Rule.java class which is used to map the <rule> element to Rule.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class RulePOJO
{

    @XmlElement(namespace = "urx:xxxxx")
    private final String name = null;
     
    @XmlElement(namespace = "urx:xxxxx")
    private final String errorType = null;
    
    @XmlElement(namespace = "urx:xxxxx")
    private final Date startDate = null;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "listId1", namespace = "urx:xxxxx")
    private final List<Long> listId1 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @XmlElement(name = "listId2", namespace = "urx:xxxxx")
    private final List<Long> listId2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public errorType getErrorType()
    {
        return errorType;
    }

    public Boolean getFlag()
    {
        return flag;
    }

    public Date getStartDate()
    {
        return startDate;
    }

    public List<Long> getListId1()
    {
        return listId1;
    }

    public List<Long> getListId2()
    {
        return listId2;
    }
}
```

the business class used for unmarshalling xml into the pojo

```
public class Retriever() throws JAXBException
    {
        Document document = Configuration.load(URI.create("urn:xxxxxx"));

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(RulesPOJO.class).createUnmarshaller();
        RulesPOJO rulesPOJO = (RulesPOJO) unmarshaller
                .unmarshal(document.getElementsByTagName("Rules").item(0));
        for(RulePOJO rulePOJO : RulesPOJO.getRulesPOJO())
        {
            // the following are coming back null
            List<Long> listId1 = rulePOJO.getListId1();
            List<Long> listId2 = rulePOJO.getListId2();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Id` is the repeating item inside listId1 and listId2 isn't it ?

Comment: @rootkonda yes its a repeating element

Comment: What I mean is don't you have to mention `Id` as the xmlelement and that is actually considered as ArrayList

Comment: @rootkonda I am not sure. Since its a list of long values, I am not exactly sure how to go about it , since creating a new class for just Id doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/xmlelementwrapper-annotation/

Comment: @rootkonda thanks a bunch, by adding XmlElementWrapper and XmlElement for both lists fixed the problem.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "listId2", namespace = "urx:xxxxx")
@XmlElement(name = "Id", namespace = "urx:xxxxx")
    private final List<Long> listId1 = new ArrayList<Long>();```

Comment: Np. Posting this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `id` is the repeating element to be treated as arraylist so as mentioned in the given link https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/xmlelementwrapper-annotation/.  You can use `XMLElementWrapper` and `XMLElement` types of annotations to denote wrapper and child elements.